# Android Animate - animate View to push it's right side views

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement something like this:

> before animating
>
> X (visibility: gone) y z
>
> after animating
>
> X (pushes y and z to the right and it got visible) y z (both are invisible)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/move"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="move"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moved"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="moved"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and you have tried nothing so far and even the requirements mentioned in a user perspective way , try something , come up with something

Comment: As you have it, you could animate the views' widths

Comment: @PavneetSingh I didn't get what you mean

Comment: @FletcherJohns I already animate them but item X seems not in relative position but absolute position! I animate item X but it doesn't push its beside views and  it will cover them instead of pushing them!

Comment: Are they in a LinearLayout?

Comment: @FletcherJohns Yes thet are.

Comment: Setting width by setLayoutParams ()?

Comment: @FletcherJohns I'm using `translateX()` method of `animate()` I don't know setting width is a good solution.